# Sum of elements of order dividing a divisor of $p-1$ in the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Let $p$ be a prime number. Let $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ denote the group of multiplicative units in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. It is well-known that

- $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})=\{1,2, ..., p-1\}$ mod $p$
- $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is cyclic.

Let $d$ be any divisor of $p-1$ different from $1.$ Then it seems to me that the sum of elements (mod $p$) in $U(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ whose multiplicative order divides $d$ is always divisible by $p$. In symbols,

$$\sum_{a \in \{1,2,..., p-1\} \text{ such that } ord(a)|d }a=0 \text{ mod } p$$

However, I have a hard time proving it. In fact, I am not even sure if it is true. I verified this claim for a few primes and it always seems to work. But I have a hard time showing it in general.

Any help with proving (or disproving) the above claim would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time,

Pawel

Comment: Hint;  Let $g$ be an element of order $d$.  Then show that multiplying by $g$ permutes the list of elements in your sum.

Comment: @lulu Thank you! That helps a lot. Would you mind if I asked you how you came up with this idea? I am always interested in how people get to an answer like that. Have you seen a similar problem before?

Comment: It's a standard group theoretic technique, used to show that character sums are $0$, that sort of thing.  For example, if $\chi: G\to \mathbb C$  is non-trivial (for $G$ some finite group) show that $\sum_{g\in G}\chi (g)=0$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you!